# Conceito de Lista circular simples

Tags: python

Eu queria saber como funciona esse processo de que o ponteiro seguinte do último elemento aponta para o primeiro elemento da lista?

Comment: A pergunta é sobre o conceito de listas circulares ou sobre a implementação em Python? Não ficou muito claro o que quer saber. Se partiu da premissa que a lista circular é uma variação da lista encadeada, seria natural que desse para adicionar, remover, imprimir e alterar a posição, correto? E o que você entende por lista infinita?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta pra ficar mais claro sobre minha dúvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eu queria saber como funciona esse processo de que o ponteiro seguinte
>   do último elemento aponta para o primeiro elemento da lista?

Funciona assim: o ponteiro de próximo elemento da lista aponta para o primeiro elemento da lista.

Piadas a parte: primeiro, em geral não precisamos implementar listas circulares (ou outras) em Python, por que as estruturas de dados fornecidas pela linguagem são suicientes para a grande maiora dos casos de uso real - as listas, dicionários, conjuntos e suas variantes.

Segundo: em Python não existem "ponteiros". Apesar de na implementação de referência até ser simples obter o número que representa o endereço de memória de um objeto, esse número não é usado. Falamos em objetos sempre. Isso é fácil arrumar, é só em vez de "ponteiro" falarmos em "referência". A frase fica "Por quê a referência seguinte do último elemento é de novo o primeiro elemento".

Terceiro, a lista normal de Python (list), não é uma lista ligada - é uma lista sequêncial em memória mesmo. A única coisa que tem de especial é uma lógica para pré-alocar o espaço ocupado pela lista em função da quantidade de elementos.

Quarto: Podemos construir nossas próprias estruturas de dados no Python, que podem inclusive se comportar como sequências ou mappings e serem usadas no lugar das listas ou dicionários do Python em quase todos os lugares. Basta que a classe que representa seu objeto tenha os "métodos mágicos" apropriados.
Há uma implementação que, para uso é equivalente a uma lista circular na biblitoeca padrão do Python que é o objeto "deque", fica no modo collections. Ela permite inserções igualmente eficientes no último ou no primeiro elementos, e "girar" o início, de forma que um elemento que estava no meio passe a ser o novo início. Não sei se a implementação do "deque" é uma lista circular.

Mas então, em uma implementação "clássica" de lista circular, em geral em uma lignuagem de mais baixo nível do que Python, um "nó" da lista só sabe de duas coisas: o valor que está armazenado no mesmo, e uma referência para o próximo nó.
Se o último nó tiver uma referência "vazia" (para Null em C), isso não seria uma lista circular. A última referência sendo para o primeiro nó, faz com que a lista "não tenha início nem fim": qualquer nó que você pegar permite que você percorra a lista toda.

Em Python, se criarmos uma classe para funcionar como nó de lista circular que tenha o método `__iter__` para iterar a lista toda, e uma forma de inserir novos elementos (por exemplo um `.append` que insira algo depois do nó atual), já temos uma lista circular - com alguns outros métodos (`__repr__`, `extend`, `__len__`) esse objeto pode ser funcional o suficente para ser usado em código de produção de forma agradável:

```
class CircularNode:
    def __init__(self, values, next=None):
        try:
            len(values)
        except TypeError:
            values = list(values)
        self.value = values[0]
        self.next = self if next is None else next
        if len(values) >= 2:
            self.extend(values[1:])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self.value
        return self.next.__getitem__(index + (1 if index < 0 else -1))

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if index == 0:
            self.value = value
            return
        return self.next.__setitem__(index + (1 if index < 0 else -1), value)

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self
        while True:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next
            if node is self:
                return

    def __len__(self):
       return sum(1 for _ in self)

    def append(self, value):
        self.next = CircularNode([value], next=self.next)

    def extend(self, values):
        for value in reversed(values):
            self.append(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Circular>[{', '.join(repr(item) for item in self)}]"
```

E isso pode ser usado assim (Exemplo em sessão interativa):

```
In [9]: a  = CircularNode(range(3))                                                                                               

In [10]: a                                                                                                                        
Out[10]: <Circular>[0, 1, 2]

In [11]: b = a.next.next                                                                                                          

In [12]: b                                                                                                                        
Out[12]: <Circular>[2, 0, 1]

In [13]: b.append(3)                                                                                                              

In [14]: a                                                                                                                        
Out[14]: <Circular>[0, 1, 2, 3]

In [15]: b                                                                                                                        
Out[15]: <Circular>[2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Não executou esse código

Comment: o que voce tentou fazer? O código tanto funciona que os exemplos acima foram feitos com ele.

Comment: Não saiu nada quando compilei no Spyder.

Comment: mas pe uma declaração de classe - depois de criada a classe, você usa a classe - a segunda listagem é um exemplo do uso da classe. 
Claro que só a declaração de classe "nao sai nada".